# how to Extract regex from json to parse sms (android)

Tags: java, android, json, regex, sms

Recently I've got a new project from my employer. He provided me with a Json file which contains 24k lines the Json contains a lot of regex's to identify sms of different type. My goal is to use regex's from the file and to detect sms in android phone with respective regular expression's.

I'm unable to figure out how can i use each and every regex in my android project

Basically what i want is to identify whether a msg in android phone matches a regex in my Json file. if it matches then it should return other fields of that object.

I'll be grateful if someone could help me out here.

Comment: I would reconsider posting that JSON on the internet.

Comment: Please read through [mcve] and [edit] your question to include the *relevant* code. As tima noted, be cautious if your link has proprietary information. If it's something that should not have been posted you can flag your question for mod attention and request they remove the revisions with the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple, really.  Generate a JSONArray from your "patterns" in the json file.

When you've gotten that far you just need to loop through each object in the array and get your regular expression from "regex".

Use Pattern and Matcher to check the field against the regex.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(my_string);
if (matcher.find()) {
    // you found a match
}
```

After that you can do whatever you want.

Edit for clarity:

```
    if (!my_json_object_from_file.isNull("rules")) {
        JSONArray rules_array = my_json_object_from_file.getJSONArray("rules");
        for (JSONObject rule_object : rules_array) {
            if (!rule_object.isNull("name")) {
                // you have a name for the rule
            }
            if (!rule_object.isNull("patterns")) {
                // you have some patterns
                JSONArray pattern_array = rule_object.getJSONArray("patterns");
                for (JSONObject pattern_object : pattern_array) {
                    // these are your pattern objects
                    if (!pattern_object.isNull("regex")) {
                        String regex = pattern_object.getString("regex");
                        // do work with the regex
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm able to retrieve the regex from JSON using above code(can see values using debugger). But as the file is too large it takes forever(never loads actually) to load on the device.I tried using Asynctask but that doesn't seems to do the trick.Can you please guide as to what i should do to solve this. P.s sorry for the noob questions ,I'm just a beginner in android development.

Comment: There is an excellent example of how to handle this here: http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2015/10/23/reading-json-file-in-stream-mode-with-gson.html